# Javascript conversion, from Prototype to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, prototypejs

I would like to update the following javascript code based on Prototype framework to jQuery framework:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
  $$('.piece').each(function(item) {
    new Draggable(item, { revert: true } );
  });

  $$('.cell').each(function(item) {
    Droppables.add(item, {
      accept: 'piece',
      onDrop: function(piece, cell) {
        cell.descendants().each(function(item) { item.remove(); } );

        piece.remove();
        piece.setStyle({ 'top': null, 'left': null });
        new Draggable(piece, { revert: true });
        cell.appendChild(piece);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The first part of the script is easy to convert:

```
$(function() {
  $('.piece').draggable(
    {
      evert: true
    }
  );

  $('.cell').droppable(
    {
      /* But here, it's more difficult. Right? ;)
      ... */
    }
  });
});
```

Have you got an idea? Any part of code is welcome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Most of it is similar. The droppable function has an accept property like Prototype, the onDrop is just called "drop(event, ui)" (the event). For "drop", $(this) will refer to the droppable item, and "ui.draggable" is the draggable element (or what you call piece).

As for what you're trying to accomplish here, I'm not quite sure I understand... Are you just trying to get the HTML of the draggable object into the droppable object?

Comment: Actually, it's a Web application to play chess (on Twitter). Here is the repository of the project: http://github.com/jsanders/twitchess

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.piece').draggable({
        revert: true
        , scope: 'piece_and_cell'
    });

    $('.cell').droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var cell = $(this);
            cell.empty();
            var piece = ui.draggable.detach()
            piece.css({top:null, left: null}).appendTo(cell);
            piece.draggable({
                revert: true
                , scope: 'piece_and_cell'
            })
        }
        , scope: 'piece_and_cell'
    });
});
```